# Outlook 2003 Form Regions

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am creating an Outlook 2003 version of a Outlook 2007 add-in for appointment items. Is it possible create a form region in Outlook 2003 for appointment items? If not, is there a work around to achieve the same level of functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick,

No, there is no form region support:(

You can subclass though.. take a look at a example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/additional_panel_Outlook.aspx

There are commercial products that may be easier such as [addin express](http://www.add-in-express.com/).